# Expand/collapse databound TreeView items with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, expand, hierarchicaldatatemplate

There are a lot of questions of this type here on SO, but all are answered, so i've decided to create a quick new one. The title is pretty self-explanatory, so here's the problem. TreeView:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
var labelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
var template = new HierarchicalDataTemplate(typeof(Node)) { ItemsSource = new Binding("Children") };
labelFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Text"));
template.VisualTree = labelFactory;
treeView.ItemTemplate = template;
```

Type i'm binding to:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

Actual binding, blank root needed for proper displaying of hierarchy:

```
var hierarchy = Helpers.GetHierarchy();
var rootNode = new Node();
rootNode.Children.Add(hierarchy);
GVSObjectStructureTreeView.ItemsSource = rootNode.Children;
```

There is a need to select/expand specific item programmatically, but when i do

```
var itemToSelect = FindTreeViewItem(treeView.ItemsSource as List<Node>, elementId);
itemToSelect.IsSelected = true;
```

nothing happens. Same for expanding. I guess the problem is in binding but can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think you will want to use an [`ObservableCollection<Node>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or some other collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, otherwise collection changes won't be reflected. If of course the children are immutable that is not an issue.

Comment: Changed List<Node> to ObservableCollection. Still no luck, select doesn't work.

Comment: I never claimed it would, it just concerns collection changes, you already had items, so obviously you did not change the collections after binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten service classes and problem was solved. Here are two recursive hierarchy helpers i've implemented (may be useful for someone else) :

```
 private static Node FindTreeViewItem(IEnumerable<Node> treeViewItems, string key)
 {
      if (treeViewItems == null) return null;
      foreach (var item in treeViewItems)
      {
         if (item.AssociatedObject.ID.Equals(key))
         {
            return item;
         }
         if (item.Children != null)
         {
            var childItem = FindTreeViewItem(item.Children, key);
            if (childItem != null)
            {
               return childItem;
            }
         }
      }
      return null;
 }

 private static void ExpandTreeViewItemParents(Node treeViewItem)
 {
     if (treeViewItem == null) return;
     if (treeViewItem.Parent != null)
     {
         treeViewItem.Parent.IsExpanded = true;
     }
     ExpandTreeViewItemParents(treeViewItem.Parent);
 }
```

Used in click handler as follows :

```
var selectedItem = FindTreeViewItem(treeView.ItemsSource as List<Node>, ID);
if (selectedItem != null)
{
     selectedItem.IsSelected = true;
     ExpandTreeViewItemParents(selectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like your class [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), so nothing will happen even if the binding is correct unless you omitted that for brevity.

Comment: Doesn't two-way databinding deals with updates without additional plumbing? Added INPC to my Node, nothing changed.

Comment: @Jaded: `TwoWay` only means that the control may change the bound source property. e.g. `TextBoxe.Text` binds `TwoWay` by default so the bound property can be edited. Any [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: Have one binding error for toolbar component in the same application window that has ugly RelativeSource FindAncestor paths, but it's not relevant to this problem i guess, so no. But i agree that the problem may be somewhere in binding syntax, although it looks correct (hierarchytemplate binds to root node Children, while TreeViewItem IsSelected is bound to child Node IsSelected property.